# Solve log equations problem [SageMath]

Tags: python, sage

Input

```
var('x')
solve((log((x**2 - x), 6) - log((6*x - 10), 6) == 0), x)
```

Output

```
[log(x^2 - x) == log(6*x - 10)]
```

But real roots are 5 and 2. What I doing wrong?

Comment: The Sage project have also a Q&A site: http://ask.sagemath.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the option `to_poly_solve=True` which have the following semantic:

> to_poly_solve`- bool (default: False); use Maxima's`
>   to_poly_solver`package to search for more possible 
>      solutions, but possibly encounter approximate solutions.
>      This keyword is incompatible with`multiplicities=True``.

So,

```
solve(..., x, to_poly_solve=True)
```

should do.

Comment: Indeed, this works. Using the brand new sagecell server, one can perform computations with Sage on a single cell: http://aleph.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSyzSUK9Q1-Qqzs8pS9XQyMlP19Co0NIyUtBVqNDUUTDTBDLAgmZaFUCmoQFE0NZWAcSq0FEoyY8vyM-pjAcbYBtSVJqqCQDFQxdd